# Excluding unit tests from external library

Tags: android, gradle, bouncycastle

I newly replaced spongyCastle by bouncyCastle in an Android project:

```
implementation "org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:$project.bouncyCastleVersion"
```

Since then on Jenkins (our CI) it seems that there are tests being executed from this lib, could this be true? I never saw external libs with units tests executing automatically. The issue is now I see many failed tests, for example:

```
org.bouncycastle.pqc.crypto.qtesla.QTeslaKeyEncodingTests.testDecodeEncodePrivateKeyQT3P    27 ms   1
 org.bouncycastle.pqc.crypto.qtesla.QTeslaKeyEncodingTests.testDecodeEncodePublicKeyQT3P
```

Is there a way to exlude al unit tets from an imported library in gradle?

Comment: what is your command to execute tests ?

Comment: ./gradlew --stacktrace testDebug createDebugCoverageReport mergeAndroidReports --continue || true

Comment: If you want to track the underlying issue with BouncyCastle: https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/661

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To exclude any unit test following can be used in **build.gradle**:

```
android {
  testOptions {
    unitTests {
      all {
        //exclude '**/QTeslaKeyEncodingTests.*'
        exclude 'org.bouncycastle/**'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your test command to this:

```
./gradlew --stacktrace testDebug --tests=your.package.name createDebugCoverageReport mergeAndroidReports --continue || true
```

Comment: I have tests running from different packages, so this wouldn't work in my case.

Comment: Are all the tests in the same module? or they are also in different modules ?

Answer (score -2):

idk if it helps, but I had some issues with my CI related to spongy castle. I solved them by ignoring linting to its packages.
In app.gradle, add:

```
  lintOptions {
    lintConfig file("lint.xml")
  }
```

**lint.xml**

```
<lint>
  <issue id="InvalidPackage">
    <!-- ignore Invalid Package check for spongycastle -->
    <ignore path="**/*spongycastle*.jar"/>
  </issue>
</lint>
```

My problem was with linting, but you can probably ignore it for testing too.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't address my question, what I need to do is disable all tests in that library, unit tests.