# Is it possible to remove a class from an imported gradle library?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, bouncycastle

I'm searching and trying already one day long to remove a class from an imported library over gradle without really getting it to work, should this be possible with Android+gradle? How to do this?

For example if I include a library like so:

```
implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.64'
```

How to remove a class by name from it? The latest thing I tried was setting in build.gradle:

```
android {
  sourceSets.main.java.filter.exclude '**/QTeslaKeyEncodingTests.*'
}
```

Following also doesn't work:

```
jar {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                exclude '**/QTeslaKeyEncodingTests.java'
                exclude '**/QTeslaKeyEncodingTests.class'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This also doesn't:

```
android{
  packagingOptions {        
    exclude 'org.bouncycastle/pqc/crypto/qtesla/QTeslaKeyEncodingTests.class'
  }
}
```

Context: why do I need this currently: when you execute "gradlew testDebug" all tests in the project run, including those present in the imported libs. I also don't know if this is a bug from bouncyCastle that they included those tests in the library but it's a problem because many tests fail.

Comment: I can't help you, but I'm curious as to why you want to do this.

Comment: Because when you execute gradlew testDebug all tests in the project run, including those present in the imported libs. I also don't know if this is a bug from bouncyCastle that they included those tests in the library but it's a problem because many tests fail.

Comment: I see, thank you for explaining. I upvoted your question so hopefully, you'll get better chances of somebody who knows how to help you sees it.

Comment: @Andy but only for java, not for Android, right?

Comment: Yes, I think that method should work, I'm still waiting for the build to complete, maybe that would solve my specific problem but this won't answer the question in the form I formulated it :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excluding unit tests from external library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60284462/excluding-unit-tests-from-external-library)

Answer (score 3):

Exclude a specific package from the  instrumentation tests (`connectedAndroidTest` gradle task) with the `notPackage` option.
For example:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunnerArguments = ["notPackage": "com.example.somelibrary"]
    }
}
```

There are plenty of potential options for filtering. The official documentation that documents all of them is at -

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner

Comment: Interesting, our project has more than 1 package, can you add multiple packages to that?

Comment: Edited it for you. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you mate. Spent hours figuring out how to do this

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to exclude files from test target as you are interested in excluding the files while running your tests.

```
sourceSets {

     androidTest {
         java {
             exclude '**/QTeslaKeyEncodingTests.java'
             exclude '**/QTeslaKeyEncodingTests.class'
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Please read question carefully. @David mentioned that he already tried this solution but it didn't work.

Comment: I see.I am sorry its my bad

Comment: This only works for own classes, but not for classes in third party imported libs through gradle's "implementation".